# Compare Array of IPs with rsyslog

Tags: arrays, json, jq, lookup-tables, rsyslog

There is a list of IPs (their quantity is changing every few minutes) stored in a log-file. The logfile only contains unique IPs (sort -u):

```
IP-Pool.log [Example]:
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
10.1.1.0
.
.
```

I would like to filter occuring connection events with rsyslog and sort them by:

- Events where $msg contains one IP of Array[IP-Pool-List]
- Events where $msg doesn't contain any IP of Array[IP-Pool-List]

Therefore I would have to put the IPs into an array so they can be compared but I haven't found a way to do so.

```
if $msg contains 'connection-event-id' then {

  if $msg contains 'Array[IP-Pool-List] then {
    -/var/log/event_contains_ip.log      
    STOP
  }
  else{
   -/var/log/event_doesnt_contain_ip.log
   STOP
  }

}
```

Would I also have to restart the rsyslogd service in order to refresh the array [IP-Pool-List], since the file is changing every few minutes ?

Is there a way to solve this with rsyslog, or is there an easier/better way to do this ?

**EDIT**

I used crontab and inotifywait to keep the IP-Pool-File up to date.

```
@reboot inotifywait -q -m -e modify /var/log/client-ips.log | 
while read -r filename events; do sort -u /var/log/client-ips.log 
-o /var/log/ips-unique.log ;done
```

I also asked this question via mail to the "rsyslog-community" their contact mail is listed at the bottom of the rsyslog documentation (https://lists.adiscon.net/mailman/listinfo/rsyslog)
They gave me the advise to use "Lookup-Tables" to solve this. Currently reading how to use them correctly. Since I am a slow learner, this should take a while.

**EDIT 2**

A new plan is starting to form:

- To get Lookup-Table going, I need to create a JSON-File, which
  contains the values I am going to build my filter with
- Update the JSON File with "reload_lookup_table" or "JQ", whenever a new IP is added to the
  IP-Pool-List.
- Use RSYSLOG Lookup-Table to filter for the given IPs and split the
  results into two seperate log files | Match.log | NoMatch.log